# How do I transfer Python numpy data to Rust ndarray data via FFI?

Tags: python, numpy, rust, ffi

My goal is to pass `a` and `b` to Rust via FFI, construct Rust `ndarray` versions of `a` and `b`, multiply them, set the result, and print the result back on the Python side.

I'm working on replicating [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/calling-into-rust-from-python/8923) example, but I'm having some trouble. As of right now, Rust reads `a` and `b` correctly, but prints zeros after the multiplication (presumably because `res`'s underlying memory has not been altered).

What is causing this?

My Python code:

```py
import numpy as np
from ctypes import c_float, addressof
from cffi import FFI

## Helper functions for Python-Rust FFI through `cffi`.
def _as_f64(num):
    """ Cast np.float64 for Rust."""
    return ffi.cast("double", num)

def _as_f64_array(x):
    """ Cast np.float64 array to a pointer to float 64s."""
    return ffi.cast("double*", x.ctypes.data)

def _as_usize(num):
    """ Cast `num` to Rust `usize`."""
    return ffi.cast("unsigned long", num)

## Instantiate `cffi` object.
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef(
    """
    void* entry(double* a_ptr, unsigned long a_rows, unsigned long a_cols,
                double* b_ptr, unsigned long b_rows, unsigned long b_cols,
                double* res_ptr, unsigned long res_rows, unsigned long res_cols);
    """
)

## Go get the Rust library.
lib = ffi.dlopen("rustlib/target/release/librustlib.dylib")

a_rows, a_cols = 5, 4
a = np.random.random((a_rows, a_cols))
b_rows, b_cols = 4, 3
b = np.random.random((b_rows, b_cols))
res_rows, res_cols = a_rows, b_cols
res = np.zeros((res_rows, res_cols))

a_ptr = _as_f64_array(a)
a_rows_c = _as_usize(a_rows)
a_cols_c = _as_usize(a_cols)
b_ptr = _as_f64_array(b)
b_rows_c = _as_usize(b_rows)
b_cols_c = _as_usize(b_cols)
res_ptr = _as_f64_array(res)
res_rows_c = _as_usize(res_rows)
res_cols_c = _as_usize(res_cols)

# this should update the memory that res_ptr points to, i.e. res
lib.entry(
    a_ptr, a_rows_c, a_cols_c,
    b_ptr, b_rows_c, b_cols_c,
    res_ptr, res_rows_c, res_cols_c
)

# should print the product of a and b, but prints zeros instead
print(res)
```

My Rust code:

```rust
use ndarray::{array, Array2};
use std::mem;

unsafe fn construct_array_2d(input: *mut f64, rows: usize, cols: usize) -> Array2<f64> {
    assert!(!input.is_null());
    ArrayViewMut2::from_shape_ptr((rows, cols), input).to_owned()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn entry(
    a: *mut f64,
    a_rows: usize,
    a_cols: usize,
    b: *mut f64,
    b_rows: usize,
    b_cols: usize,
    res: *mut f64,
    res_rows: usize,
    res_cols: usize,
) {
    let a_rust = unsafe { construct_array_2d(a, a_rows, a_cols) };
    let b_rust = unsafe { construct_array_2d(b, b_rows, b_cols) };
    let mut res_rust = unsafe { construct_array_2d(res, res_rows, res_cols) };

    mem::replace(
        &mut res_rust,
        mult(&a_rust.to_owned(), &b_rust.to_owned())
    );

    mem::forget(a_rust);
    mem::forget(b_rust);
    mem::forget(res_rust);
}

fn mult(a: &Array2<f64>, b: &Array2<f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
    a.dot(b)
}
```

Comment: *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*  (like documentation) is off-topic for Stack Overflow; I've removed that from your question.

Comment: Is your main goal to become familiar with FFI or to write python extensions for fast array operations? If it's the latter, you might want to check out the [pyo3](https://crates.io/crates/pyo3) and [numpy](https://github.com/PyO3/rust-numpy) crates for a higher level way to access python numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PyO3, it's a Rust binding for Python, including tools for creating native Python extension modules. The following is an example of how you can move ndarrays from and to Rust.

repo: [rust-numpy](https://github.com/PyO3/rust-numpy)